# Get news and convert to plain text php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I want to know if there's a way to chose a random link from a news website, get the page and remove all but text to be stored in a database with php cli. I have no limitations on what can be installed as far as php extensions. If there is no easy way to do this, is there a news service that supplies plain text news?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope - not from a 'website'... html will vary from site to site and too complex to filter from one source - add multiple sources and the mission is impossible.

That's the bad news.  The good news is that there is a way:

Most "news" site provide their content, or a portion of the content, in RSS feeds.  Do some research on `RSS2` and `ATOM` protocols and your answer is in there...

Start here: http://www.whatisrss.com

Comment: This works, I'm not sure if you will get the rep because the question was put on hold but thank you anyway!